# How to add a subclass of JButton to a JPanel

Tags: java

I have a class which is a sub class of JButton. I have to add it into a JPanel but my problem is that I do not know how to go about it as I buttons, labels etc to JPanels. 
Please help.

Comment: Add the component to the panel just like you would any component

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your subclass of `JButton` is called `MyButton`. First you create an instance of `MyButton`:

```
MyButton btn = new MyButton("Text");
```

And let's say that your `JPanel` is called `panel1`. You can add your button into the `JPanel` by calling the `add` method:

```
panel1.add(btn);//btn is the object that you just created.
```

And then you can see that your panel has the button on it. You can also set the buttons properties like bounds and background after/before adding it to the panel.